# ILoggingBuilder does not have AddEventSourceLogger with 0 parameters. How to initialize this logging

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, logging, azure-web-app-service

'ILoggingBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddEventSourceLogger' and no accessible extension method 'AddEventSourceLogger' accepting a first argument of type 'ILoggingBuilder' could be found

```
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            // Requires `using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;`
            // logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddDebug();
            logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
        })
        .UseApplicationInsights()
        .UseStartup<StartupConsole>()
        .UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => options.ValidateScopes = false);
```

I am currently using .net-core 2.1 and have nuget for using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource) NuGet package.

Reference: [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#eventsource-provider)

Comment: Also make sure you add `using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;`